# Gradient Colors for Label in LWUIT

Tags: lwuit

Can anyone tell me how to make a `Label` or `TextField` with two gradient color in LWUIT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try to use the LWUIT Resource Editor? In this program you can customize every Components's style that you want. It has an special option for do what you want. In codenameone, you can find a similar editor (is better than LWUIT editor).

For the LWUIT editor go here http://lwuit.java.net/

Codename http://www.codenameone.com/